# Using Two UI Pickers in 1 VC, Handling Delegate methods

Tags: ios, swift, picker

I have 2 pickers in 1 VC and know that this should be handled by using if else to identify which delegate methods each should follow. However Im new to getting my head around this and im not sure what i should be returning on my methods in order to have them work correctly.

Here is the code, I have just used 0 and "" to prevent code errors for now until I can get the correct returns sorted out.

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    if pickerView == repsPicker {
        return 1
    } else if pickerView == setsPicker {
        return 1
    }
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerView == repsPicker {
        return repPickerValues.count
    } else if pickerView == setsPicker {
        return self.setsPickerValues.count
    }
    return 0
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView == repsPicker {
        return repPickerValues[row]
    } else if pickerView == setsPicker {
        return self.setsPickerValues[row]
    }
    return ""
}
```

Comment: cannot understand what you want

Comment: im using 2 pickers, they both need delegates, this is done with if else, but they need to return independent values, using my current code im only managing to return 1 value for both which wont work. Basically just need some help with how to get the correct values returned

Comment: Unless we know what `repPickerValues` and `setsPickerValues` is and how you initialize them, we cannot provide an answer.

Comment: no problem, they are array of strings, e.g. var repPickerValues = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let repPickerValues = ["America", "Mexico", "Canada"]
let setsPickerValues = ["India", "China", "Malaysia", "Singapore"]
```

If these are your values, then you will have 3 options on 1st picker and 4 options on 2nd picker.

Adding below lines will call those functions

```
repsPicker.delegate = self
setsPicker.delegate = self
```

And your view controller class should conform to `UIPickerViewDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDataSource`. Like

```
class ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDatSource {

}
```

This function will tell picker view how many options are to be shown

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerView == repsPicker {
        return repPickerValues.count
    } else if pickerView == setsPicker {
        return self.setsPickerValues.count
    }
    return 0
}
```

This function is responsible for placing values in picker view

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView == repsPicker {
        return repPickerValues[row]
    } else if pickerView == setsPicker {
        return self.setsPickerValues[row]
    }
    return ""
}
```

Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: ignore previous comment, it seems i missed some delegate stuff for one of them and it now feeds correctly so this was kind of the answer, close enough

Answer (score 2):

You can set tag to each picker so that you can differentiate between them. Set `pickerView.tag` with two different values, and in each delegate method check the tag value to determine the return value.

Comment: i saw that but it looks like poor practice to double up on methods, this way should work fine i just cant get my head around the last bit, there shouldnt be a difference between using tag or name and it would lead to this same situation

Answer (score 0):

I can see several options here  :

1. Use different delegate objects for each picker

   ```
   picker1.delegate = firstDelegate()
   picker2.delegate = secondDelegate()
   ```

   Implement the desired delegate methods differently in each of the delegate objects.
2. Keep a reference to each picker in your view controller (or IBOutlet)

   ```
   let picker1 = ...
   let picker2 = ...
   ```

   Then in your delegate method(s)

   ```
   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
       if pickerView == picker1 { 
           ... 
       }
   }
   ```